# Moving multiple files from a single folder to multiple folders according to their name

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I have a folder which contains files of the following type-
    boxer_1.jpg
    boxer_2.jpg
    american_bulldog_120.jpg
    american_bulldog_119.jpg
Here each alphabetical name represents the breed of an animal and the number represents its count.
I want to create folders from the names of the file names and then place the files in their respective folders.
I want the folder names to be just the alphabetical name.

I have managed to create folders from the names of files.
First, I removed the digits, underscore and extension name from the file names and then placed them in a list.
Then I created folders from the list.

```
  files = os.listdir("data_path")
  import re
  cleaned_files = []
  for each in files: # To remove the digits and underscore.
     cleaned_files.append(re.sub(r'[0-9\_]','',each))

  new_files = [] # To remove the .jpg extension
  for each in distinct_files:
     new_files.append(re.sub('.jpg','',each))

  from collections import OrderedDict # To make list distinct 
  distinct_files = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(new_files))

  path_dir = 'Modified_Dataset_Path' #Creation of folders
  for folder in distinct_files:
     os.mkdir(os.path.join(path_dir,folder))
```

I am not unable to proceed from here, how to place files to the respective folders.
Any other approach to solve this problem is also welcome.
P.S- The dataset is [Oxford IIIT Pet dataset](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/pets/) if anyone wants to try to test their approach.

Comment: Why are you removing digits? What are the names of the newly created folders?

Comment: I am removing digits because the total distinct file names are 3000 because of the ordering of the digits. The name of the new folders are just the alphabetical name like boxer,americanbulldog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do the same processing on each file, then move it to that directory.

```
cleaned_files = []
new_files = []
for f in files
    cleaned_files=(re.sub(r'[0-9\_]','',f))
    new_files=(re.sub('.jpg','',cleaned_files))
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(data_path,f),os.path.join(Modified_Dataset_Path,new_files))
```

With data_path being the directory the original files are located and Modified_Dataset_Path being the directory where all your new directories are located.

Comment: Though I have a question, how the extension 'jpg' got retained in the file name in the new dataset path?

Comment: @Mark So the shutil.copy takes in a source and a destination, and the source is a file and the destination is a directory so it copies the original file to the destination directory.  I just do the modifying on the file to find what the destination folder will be called.